# Administrator user not able to login to community

Tags: community

I have setup a Salesforce community and selected System Administrator to login to a community.

[image]

I am not able to login with any Admin user but all my community users work. When I look at the login history I see I see:

> No community access

What do I need to do to enable Admin users to get community access?

Comment: How are admin users login in ?

Comment: Through a custom visualforce page. that calls Site.login(username, password, startUrl);

Comment: For employee login or admin,I don't think site.login will work .On login page usually there is a different link for employees and admin go through different route

Comment: @MohithShrivastava ok what controller command do I need to use to login admins or employees?

Comment: @ThysMichels did you managed to find a solution for your problem? Just have the same exact issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to drop a link on your Site Page which will have a label to help employees Log in via that .SFDC labels as "If you are Employee Log in here" .

The URL for this login will look like below

```
https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=/servlet/networks/session/create?site=0DME0000000fxWx&inst=E
```

Now if you notice the site param has an Id there attached .You will need to get your site Id from going to Sites in Set up menu and inspect element on chrome browser or other browser to get the Site Id .

You can also query for this Id .I will recommend to use labels so you can configure each time .

Also you will need to encode the StartURL parameter (URLENCODE).

Comment: What does inst parameter do?
Please refer to my question... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157481/what-is-the-inst-parameter-for-in-our-case-inst-0

Comment: This no longer correct. Not sure if it was at the time in 2016, but Salesforce has a setting for this where don't have to do a crazy URL parameter. (Clever trick though...)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by going to Experience Cloud Workspace and under Login & Registration, checking 'Allow employees to log in directly to an Experience Cloud site'

That other answer should be changed. But I have to give credit to a clever solution to add the session site switch parameter under &startURL=

[image]