# What is the inst parameter for ( in our case inst=0 )?

Tags: community, customer-community, url, portal

Here is our implementation of a JS custom button/link to take our internal users to their own customer portal. This link works for us. We have hacked at this for hours until we landed on the "right" syntax (Not much documentation about "//servlet/networks/session/create"). Now that we have it working we want to know WHY/HOW?

I have a few questions about why and how. But firstly I want to understand the inst parameter because it is not obvious nor can I find any documentation. And it seems like there are main values to be used with this inst parameter (we used 0), based on various blogs I have seen. What is inst for?

The main purpose of this button is to log our already logged in internal user into our customer portal as a specific customer utilising the internal persons existing session.

```
window.open("https://customdomain.my.salesforce.com//servlet/networks/session/create?
site={!ourSiteId}&
url=https://customsite.force.com/portal?accountid={!Account.Id}&
inst=O","_blank");
```

EDIT:
We were able to use inst=1 inst=D and removed it altogether.
On the double back slash above, we were able to remove it also.
It made no difference, session was granted and pages redirected happily.

Here is our final working solution:

```
window.open("https://customdomain.my.salesforce.com/servlet/networks/session/create?
site={!ourSiteId}&
url=https://customsite.force.com/portal?accountid={!Account.Id}","_blank");
```

What is inst????

Comment: @Ashwani - I will attempt your suggestion on old post. to try inst=1.
I have seen others use various values like "D" so I feel like it is not a boolean parameter???

Comment: Change this inst parameter did nothing from what I can see